# How to rewrite merge on new Rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have old Rxjs merge:

```
Observable.merge(this.timers).subscribe(x => {
      let subscription = x.subscribe((value: ITimer) => {});

});
```

How to rewrite it on new Rxjs notation?

I have tried import this:

```
import { merge } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Comment: What is `this.timers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see: `merge` is still part of rxjs, it doesn't live as an operator... It is just a factory from which you can create a new observable out of n...

```js
const { merge, from } = rxjs;

const a$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const b$ = from(['hello', 'world', 'dude']);

merge(a$, b$).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha256-Nihli32xEO2dsnrW29M+krVxoeDblkRBTkk5ZLQJ6O8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```